# Aligning part of a select option's text on the left and part on the right?

Tags: html, css, selection

I have a select box and I need to have some of the options' text aligned to the left with the rest to the right, like this:

```
| option 1      0.5 |
| option 2      1.5 |
```

Is that possible? I thought about putting div's in the option, but in searching to see if that's allowed I ran across several places that said it wasn't.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`option` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6) content is taken as plain text (no tags are recognized), so there is no direct way to do it. As a clumsy workaround, you can hand-format the options using a monospace font and use no-break spaces:

```html
    <style>
    select, option { font-family: Consolas,  monospace; }
    </style>
    <select>
    <option>option 1          0.5
    <option>option 2          1.5
    <option>one more option 110.5
    </select>
```

(where the spaces inside the `option` elements are no-break spaces; use `&nbsp;` for them if you don’t know how to type no-break spaces in your authoring environment).

A completely different workaround, or approach, is the replace the `select` element by a set of checkboxes (or, depending on desired logic, radio buttons) and associated labels. You can then represent this data in a table and set suitable formatting on it:

```html
    <table>
    <tr><td><input type=checkbox> <td>option 1 <td align=right>0.5
    <tr><td><input type=checkbox> <td>option 2<td align=right>1.5
    <tr><td><input type=checkbox> <td>one more option <td align=right>110.5
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its kind of a problem as you cant put a div inside a select tag like you stated.
The only option inside a select tag is  and you can read about it more here: [optgroup](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp)

Although that won't help you much as you are trying to edit inside an option tag itself.
I would suggest that you would try to sort it out using spaces in collaboration with the select box size so to make it fit your preferred alignment

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I am continuing to work with a workaround in which suitable spaces are inserted.

```css
select option {
     font-family: monospace;
 }
```

```html
<select>
  <option>TEXT ONE&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0.02</option>
  <option>LONG TEXT&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1.00</option>
  <option>TEXT&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;100.00</option>
</select>
```

I usually solve that with some JavaScript code.

```js
max_chars_col_1 = Math.max('TEXT ONE'.length, 'LONG TEXT'.length, ...);

option.innerHTML = 'TEXT ONE' + '&#160'.repeat( max_chars_col_1 - 'TEXT ONE'.length + max_chars_col_2 - '0.02'.length + 1 ;
```